# Store Foreach in user profile

Tags: user-meta, php

I use a foreach to get visits / visitors per month with Analytics API.

I need to store the results in the user profile the way it is displayed with an echo.

I tried this but I don't get the right value (I get only one value) :

```
$fromDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-365 days'));
$toDate = date('Y-m-d');   
$ga->requestReportData($profileId,array('yearmonth'),array('visitors', 'visits'), '-yearmonth', null, $fromDate, $toDate); 
$i = 1;
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)
      {
       $my_graph = "{Visiteurs: '".$result->getVisitors()."',Visites: '".$result->getVisits()."',number: '".(-$i++)."',},\n";
      } 
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'my_great_graph',  $my_graph );
```

I would like to save in a single field (my_great_graph) something like :

```
  {Visiteurs: '8',Visites: '9',number: '-1',},
  {Visiteurs: '72',Visites: '83',number: '-2',},
  {Visiteurs: '96',Visites: '104',number: '-3',},
  {Visiteurs: '93',Visites: '119',number: '-4',},
  {Visiteurs: '72',Visites: '81',number: '-5',},
  {Visiteurs: '32',Visites: '38',number: '-6',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-7',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-8',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-9',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-10',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-11',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-12',},
  {Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-13',},
```

**EDIT 1**

With the answer from s_ha_dum, I have this stored in my database :

a:13:{i:0;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:10;s:7:"Visites";i:11;s:6:"number";i:0;}i:1;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:72;s:7:"Visites";i:83;s:6:"number";i:-1;}i:2;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:96;s:7:"Visites";i:104;s:6:"number";i:-2;}i:3;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:93;s:7:"Visites";i:119;s:6:"number";i:-3;}i:4;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:72;s:7:"Visites";i:81;s:6:"number";i:-4;}i:5;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:32;s:7:"Visites";i:38;s:6:"number";i:-5;}i:6;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-6;}i:7;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-7;}i:8;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-8;}i:9;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-9;}i:10;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-10;}i:11;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-11;}i:12;a:3:{s:9:"Visiteurs";i:0;s:7:"Visites";i:0;s:6:"number";i:-12;}}

So now, I have to find a way to display it like above 
for example :

{Visiteurs: '0',Visites: '0',number: '-13',},

Comment: Noob, that code should be unserialized after `get_user_meta`. Just process the array much as you were originally trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: `$my_graph =`. At every iteration you are resetting the entire string to a new value. You need `$my_graph .=` -- notice the `.`-- to concatenate a string together. That is a PHP syntax problem.

I don't think I would do it this way though. `update_usermeta()` will serialize an array or object if it needs to so this...

```
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'my_great_graph',  $ga->getResults()  );
```

... would store your raw data for use later. Or...

```
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result)  {
         $my_graph[] = array(
            'Visiteurs' => $result->getVisitors(),
            'Visites' => $result->getVisits(),
            'number' =>  (-$i++),
         );
} 
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'my_great_graph',  $my_graph );
```

... should store the processed data in such a way that it can be used in multiple ways later. A processed string is difficult to use for anything but an `echo`.

`get_user_meta($user_id, 'my_great_graph')` would automatically un-serialize the data for you.

Comment: I see what you mean. I should save the data like you said. But I got an error : T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ')'